# E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list (Suite)

Tags: error-handling

I'm new to Ubuntu and I was trying to download gazebo 11 and I did but now every time I try to update or install it's keep coming up with this error saying

E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

These are the file contents

deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable
bionic main

Can you help me please?
Thank you

Comment: There is an error in line 1 of the file mentioned. That directory is empty on a clean/new install, so it's been added by a user on your system with `sudo` rights. The file needs to be corrected (entry deleted, made a comment, or file erased) but we cannot see the file so can't advise as to what's wrong.

Comment: If you post the contents of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list` we might see what's wrong.

Comment: I tried to see the content of the file and it came out like this

Comment: 1 deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable
     2 bionic main

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list`...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list` or `sudo pico /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list`

Note: below, change "focal" to your current release name, as seen in:

`lsb_release -a | grep -i Codename`

Replace whatever is in the .list file with this:

```
deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable focal main
```

Then do:

`sudo apt-get update`